# Creating User Database Following Tutorials

Tags: php, database

I am following the tutorials here: http://davidjkelley.net/?p=48 and here:  and here:http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ . They are all interconnected and are meant to create the same database for the user. It's meant to create a userdatabase on an android application (which I am making) using SQLite, PHP, and MySQL. Currently, I have the user login and registration screen set up and ready to go from the androidhive screen design tutorial. Following that tutorial, I have created the table for the users in PHPMyAdmin as directed by the tutorial (both the androidhive and davidjkelly). Following the davidjkelly tutorial at the moment so that I can create a seperate API to connect the app and database together, I don't know where to put the PHP files as directed or exactly if I am given everything that I need. Can someone please take a look and help me figure this out? I am using Windows 7 and localhost/phpmyadmin. I understand that PHPMyAdmin is usually only used for websites but according to the tutorial, it is used so that the app can contain the userdatabase online. (Which is what I want so that I don't have to save usernames and things in the Preferences files or onto a device and that way my database can be online and as long as the user of the Android app has internet, they should be able to acess it) If I am wrong, please correct me. Please help me to figure out what to do from here. Also, I am not quite sure what to tag this question as so feel free to fix any wrong tags :p

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/ -- this was the screen design screen I was talking about by the way, sorry about that!

Comment: You need a more precise question than "help me figure this out".

Comment: More specifically, I'm stuck at the beginning of part 2 of davidjkelly's walkthrough where it says "In the root directory of your localhost/web server, add a new folder, “android_api”. Within that folder, add another folder, “include”." Where exactly is the root directory and do I acess it from files using for example an xampp search and then going through the files there or can I create the PHP files in the actual web browser when I am in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is a tool that lets you manage your MySQL database so that's not it. Considering you have a XAMPP installation, your root directory should be c:\xampp\local\htdocs\ or something similar (this is what it is on my computer). You can just access it using Windows Explorer and create the directory there.

Comment: Ok thanks, also really quick, can't I just create the php files complete seperate with an extension of .php and then add them into the source directory and have it still work the same?

Comment: Yes but you can't test it if they're not visible to Apache (which is part of the pack of software that XAMPP runs for you).